# Redux - how to update an item in an array

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a very basic notes app. Similar to iphone notes where you press on a note item to update that item.

I have made a function in my Reducer to update an item. But the item does not get updated, it stays the same after I call it. It could be how I am rendering it if this isn't the problem.

Here is the case in the Reducer function:

```
const tagReducer = (state = [], action) => {

    switch (action.type) {

        case 'NEW_LIST':
             //add tags and mentions later
            const { id, title, tags, mentions } = action.payload;
            return [
                ...state,
                {
                    id: id,
                    title: title,
                    tags: tags,
                    mentions: mentions
                }
            ]
        case 'UPDATE_LIST':

            return state.map((item, index) => {
                if (item.id == action.payload.id) {
                    item = { 
                        ...item,
                        title: action.payload.title,
                        tags: action.payload.tags,
                        mentions: action.payload.mentions
                    }
                }
                return item
            })

        default: 
            return state;
    }
};


export default tagReducer;
```

Here is what happens when a note (list) is saved - a NEW_LIST action occurs or an UPDATE_LIST action occurs.

```
    save = () => {
        if (this.props.route.params.data !== null) {
            this.props.updateList(
                id = this.props.route.params.id,
                title = this.state.title,
                tags = this.state.tags,
                mentions = this.state.mentions
            )
        } else {
            this.props.newList(
                title = this.state.title, 
                tags = this.state.tags,
                mentions = this.state.mentions
            )
        }
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
    }
```

And here are the actions:

```
let nextId = 0;

export const newList = (title, tags, mentions) => (
    {
        type: 'NEW_LIST',
        payload: {
            id: ++nextId,
            title: title,
            tags: tags,
            mentions: mentions
        }
    }
);

export const updateList = (title, tags, mentions, id) => (
    {
        type: 'UPDATE_LIST',
        payload: {
            id: id,
            title: title,
            tags: tags,
            mentions: mentions
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: you're mapping your state here... is it an array? can you add your initial state to the question?

Comment: the initial state is an empty array. I have updated to include the whole reducer

Comment: Ok your reducer seems to be correct. could you share more code (component, actions)

Comment: Ok I was thinking that too. Just added some more code. Thanks

Comment: The syntax when you call a function with parameters seems incorrect. This: `id = this.props.route.params.id,`

Comment: Yeah it does seem off. It's the id of the list that is selected to update. I log it as a test and it seems to work.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I've got the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    case 'UPDATE_LIST':
        return state.map((item, index) => {
            if (item.id === action.payload.id) {
                return { 
                    ...item,
                    title: action.payload.title,
                    tags: action.payload.tags,
                    mentions: action.payload.mentions
                }
            }
            return item
        })
```

Comment: I tried that and it gives me the same result I currently have.